Image is rotating to left in Visualforce Page using RenderAs="pdf"
I'm facing an issue: I'm creating a PDF and using the image stored in the files object. I'm creating a Visualforce page with RenderAs="pdf". The image is appearing, but it's rotating to the left side. It works fine in HTML but not in PDF. How can I display the image as it appears in the file preview?
<apex:image url="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!imageUrl}"/>


Is it really being rotated, or is it translating (i.e. moving) from, say, the right side of your page to the left side? In either case, it's good to keep in mind that the library Salesforce uses to convert HTML into a PDF, FlyingSaucer, can only handle up to CSS 2.1. So if you have something like transform:rotate(-90deg), then it won't work. Showing us more of your Visualforce page will be important for people to understand the issue you're experiencing. Please [edit] your question to add more of it.

Just to clarify - the image (is this a jpg?) appears 90° rotated anticlock wise?

hello, Derek image is rotating anticlockwise 90°. The image size is 3024x4032 pixels. but when a smaller size image is there it's taking perfectly.
<apex:image url="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!imageUrl}" style="width: 50%; height: 50%;"/>

hello Felix, image is jpg and it's rotating anticlock wise
